# Retrieve data from FeatureClass

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, features

I have :

- FeatureClass (Structure)
- column (Type)
- column (OID)

I am trying to get the (Type) for specific OID.
I tried to use this code but it dose not work.

```
IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;
IFeatureClass testFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("Structure");
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
queryFilter.SubFields = "Type";
queryFilter.WhereClause = "OBJECTID = " + feature.OID;
IFeatureCursor fCursor = testFeatureClass.Search(queryFilter, true);
```

I don't know what is the wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work"?  Exception? Zero features in the cursor?  Feature has no data value for the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get field value by doing the following.  1. [Select your feature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000088000000). 
2. Cursor through feature to see if selection set is > 1 (below is code example for step 2).

```
IFeatureSelection pFSel = default(IFeatureSelection);
pFSel = pFLayer;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISelectionSet2 pSelSet = default(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ISelectionSet2);
pSelSet = pFSel.SelectionSet;
if (pSelSet.Count < 1) {
    MsgBox("No Features Selected")
    return;
}

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor pFCursor = null;
pSelSet.Search(null, false, pFCursor);

IFeature pFeature = default(IFeature);
pFeature = pFCursor.NextFeature;
// Get First Feature
if (pFeature == null) {
    Interaction.MsgBox("No Features Selected!");
    // Just in case, but probably already taken care of earlier
    return;
}

long lFIndex = 0;
lFIndex = pFCursor.FindField(m_strGridIndexField);
// Replace with your field name
if (lFIndex > -1) {
    // Substute the correct data type to match the field type
    while ((pFeature != null)) {
        m_fValue = pFeature.Value(lFIndex);
        // Do something with the value stored in fValue
        pFeature = pFCursor.NextFeature;
    }
}
```